# Why am I receiving - PHP Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a custom plugin for my WordPress Site. My ecommerce platform is WooCommerce. The custom plugin processes a webhook and loads the balance of an internal wallet system. I can't understand why I am getting this error. Here is my PHP file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Prompt Coins
 * Description: Adds an internal wallet feature for users called Prompt Coins
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Me
 */

 // Set the error log location to the plugin directory
ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . '/error_log.txt');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');

define('PROMPT_COINS_WEBHOOK_SECRET', 'SECRETKEY');

// Create custom meta field for Prompt Coins
function prompt_coins_user_meta($user) {
?>
    <h3>Prompt Coins</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="prompt_coins">Prompt Coins</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="prompt_coins" id="prompt_coins" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'prompt_coins', true)); ?>" class="regular-text" />
                <br />
                <span class="description">Enter the number of Prompt Coins for this user.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'prompt_coins_user_meta');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'prompt_coins_user_meta');

// Save custom meta field
function prompt_coins_save_user_meta($user_id) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'prompt_coins', $_POST['prompt_coins']);
}
add_action('personal_options_update', 'prompt_coins_save_user_meta');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'prompt_coins_save_user_meta');

// Shortcode to display Prompt Coins balance
function prompt_coins_shortcode() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prompt_coins = get_user_meta($user_id, 'prompt_coins', true);
    return $prompt_coins;
}
add_shortcode('prompt_coins', 'prompt_coins_shortcode');

function prompt_coins_woocommerce_webhook() {
    $payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE'];

    // Log headers and payload
    error_log("Webhook headers: " . json_encode(getallheaders()));
    error_log("Webhook payload: " . json_encode($payload));

    // Check if the webhook signature header is present
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE'])) {
        http_response_code(400);
        exit('Missing webhook signature');
    }

    // Verify the webhook signature
    $calculated_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', file_get_contents('php://input'), PROMPT_COINS_WEBHOOK_SECRET, true));
    if ($signature !== $calculated_signature) {
        http_response_code(401);
        exit('Invalid webhook signature');
    }

    if (!$payload || $payload['status'] !== 'completed') {
        return;
    }

    $user_id = $payload['customer_id'];
    $coins_to_add = 0;

    // Calculate coins to add based on products in the order
    foreach ($payload['line_items'] as $item) {
        $coins_to_add += $item['quantity'] * 100;
    }

    $current_coins = get_user_meta($user_id, 'prompt_coins', true);
    $new_coins = $current_coins + $coins_to_add;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'prompt_coins', $new_coins);
}

// Register custom REST API route for the webhook
function prompt_coins_register_webhook_route() {
    register_rest_route('prompt-coins/v1', '/webhook', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'prompt_coins_woocommerce_webhook',
    ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'prompt_coins_register_webhook_route');
```

Here is the outputted log;

```
[10-May-2023 18:56:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE" in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/prompt-coins/prompt-coins.php on line 54
```

Based on the error log, it appears that the "HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE" header is missing in the webhook headers, which causes the warning and the 400 error response code. This might be due to a misconfiguration in the WooCommerce webhook settings or a server configuration issue.

- I have removed the secret key for obvious reasons.

I have deleted the webhook, re-added it, that didn't work. I have checked the status of the webhook and it fires correctly when sent to a test website.

My only guess now is my hosting provider maybe removing the headers?

There seems to be a very long wait to ask an agent with Go Daddy so I am reaching out here, for maybe a sensible response.

Comment: To be clear, you understand the literal meaning behind the error message, right? The array key doesn't exist. So your question is really "why is it missing", right?

Comment: I understand the Array Key doesn't exist and the security check cannot be confirmed. Why its missing would be my question.

Comment: The reason I asked was because the title of your question implies something different. It might help to reframe things. For instance, I have no idea what `HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE` is or why it should exist in the first place. The assumption is that it should be coming from whatever is sending the webhook to you. Before going to your hosting provider, I'd make sure that whatever is sending you data is in fact setting the header. Making the assumption that someone is removing it before getting to you might lead you down an incorrect path.